# Distribution of waiting times for a non- homogeneous Poisson point process

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes, exponential-distribution, poisson-process

In a (homogeneous) Poisson process on $\left[0,\infty\right]$ with rate $\lambda$, the waiting time between events is distributed $\text{Exp}\left(\lambda\right)$, i.e.
$$p\left(t\right)\propto e^{-\lambda t}$$

For a nonhomogeneous process with intensity $\lambda\left(t\right)$, am I correct in generalizing the waiting time distribution, starting from some time $t_{0}$, as follows?
$$p\left(t\mid t_{0}\right)\propto e^{-\int_{t_{0}}^{t}\lambda\left(\tau\right)d\tau}$$

Comment: I think sometimes it helps to take a step back when looking at generalizations. Let $P(t)$ be the probability that an event has not occurred. Then what is the probability that an event has not occurred by time $t + \Delta t$? Well, that is given by
$$ P(t + \Delta t) = P(t)[1 - \lambda(t) \Delta t], $$
where we have assumed that $\Delta t$ is so small that only a single event could occur. I think from here it is easy to see that your generalization is reasonable.